# Resize UIImageView in UITableViewCell , with textlabel dynamically

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel, tableview

i want to one size UIimageview for all cell , but
when the high size of cell is change the image is changed i want to one size of UIimage

```
     UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(!cell){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    }

   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"England.png"];
   cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 2, 0, 25, 25 );
   cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   UIFont * myfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
   cell.textLabel.text = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
   cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
   cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
   cell.textLabel.font = myfont;
   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    return cell;



-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * description = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize size = [description sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(190,40) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        return size.height+50;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the codes

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 5);
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    UILabel *label = nil;

    cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

        [label setTag:1];



        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    }
    NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [label setText:text];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN-10, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN+30, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];





    UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(128,5, 32, 32)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"England.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
    [imv release];


    return cell;

}
```